# Optimizing interleaved VBO

Tags: opengl, vbo

I've hopefully understood the following correct:
When making different VBO:s in OpenGL for vertices, normals and indices I can use less memory because of reusing but it isn't as effective.

When using interleaved VBO:s the normal routine is that the same vertices and normals will be written more than once, right?

My question is if the use of more memory is something people just accept for the gain in speed, or is it worth it to do some kind of trick to "reuse" already given data with indices or something similar?

Comment: There should not be a difference in memory usage for using interleaved VBOs vs separate VBOs. For example if you originally had one VBO for positions and one VBO for normals each with n elements you will now have one VBO with positions and normals alternating that has 2n elements so total memory usage does not change.

Comment: Are you asking what the performance and memory usage difference is between indexed rendering and non-indexed rendering?

Comment: Whether you use interleaved VBOs or not, you still have to produce 1 discrete combination of vertex attributes per-vertex. Your question seems to imply that you think you can use a smaller set of vertex normals if you use separate vertex pointers, but the array of normals must have the same length as positions. That said, you might be able to better align memory if you pack everything into an interleaved VBO. You might be able to avoid adding padding to each separate array of attributes, which ***can*** actually save you memory.

Answer (score 2):

interleaved VBO holds essentially a array of structs:

```
struct vertexAttr{
    GLfloat posX, posY, posZ;
    GLfloat normX, normY, normZ;
}

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vert);
vertexAttr* verts = new vertexAttr[numVerts];
//fill verts
glBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVerts, verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW​);
delete[] verts;

glBindProgram(prog);
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttr, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(vertexAttr), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(normAttr, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(vertexAttr), offsetof(vertexAttr, normX));
```

you still need to use a separate buffer for the indexes.

Comment: You can store the indices in the same buffer. Just not interleaved. You can allocate a single buffer that has enough space for both vertex data and indices, and store the back to back. I don't think it's done very commonly, but it works just fine.

Comment: You know... I never once thought about doing anything like that. That is pretty clever ;) That said, you definitely have to bind the buffer object to two places for that to work. Once to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` when you setup your pointers and then to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` before you draw. So there is some truth to ratchetfreak's statement, they just do not have to be *separate*, as you mention.

Comment: Right, you end up binding the same buffer to both those targets. I used this approach for some code that I plan to open source any day now (a simple library to draw some common geometric shapes with modern OpenGL). I mainly went with it because I thought it would be fun to try. I don't expect it to offer very significant benefits. It does potentially reduce some buffer mapping overhead in the driver, e.g. for creating the GPU mappings of the buffer memory. One limitation is that the usage flags are shared. So you couldn't have DYNAMIC for the vertex data, and STATIC for the indices.